# Tailwind print hidden modifier not working?

Tags: printing, tailwind-css, hidden

Tailwind version: 3.3.3

I'm trying to hide some divs and other elements. Documentation says it works like this:

print:hidden, see code below.

```
<div class="print:hidden border-2 col-span-1 justify-center"></div>
                    <div class="print:hidden bg-white col-span-5"></div>
                      <p class="print:text-3xl ">TESTOOOO</p>
```

nothing happens, tried the text-3xl, but thats also not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with:

```
@media print {    
  .no-print{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ... rest of tailwind config
  extend: {
    screens: {
      print: { raw: 'print' },
      screen: { raw: 'screen' },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).